# Any method to get layer's parent view?

Tags: ios, view, calayer

Yes, you read it right "layer's parent view". I'm not sure if its the right term to use but what I mean is, I have a layer added as sublayer of a view. I wanted to know if there is any way to get the view from the layer.

Comment: How have you lost the association between the view and the layers?  You must be doing something very strange.

Comment: I have a subclass of CALayer and it is a reusable module. It could be added to any view. Now I have a situation where I want to get some info from the view once it is added as a sublayer. I could easily solve this by maintaing a property of the view in the layer subclass, but I wanted to know if there is any better way.

Answer (score 15):

This question is quite old, but accessing `CALayer`'s parent view is easy as:

`layer.delegate`

If you look into a debugger, you'll see that the `delegate` property is populated with the `UIView` containing the Layer, and if not, you can recursively check until you get the main `CALayer` directly hosted in the view.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410984-delegate

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this using KVC.

```
UIView *View1=[UIView new];
View1.tag=1;
[View1.layer setValue:View1 forKey:@"LayerObject"];

UIView *View2=[UIView new];
View2.tag=2;
[View2.layer setValue:View2 forKey:@"LayerObject"];

NSLog(@"Your Layers superView = %@",[View2.layer.superlayer valueForKey:@"LayerObject"]);
```

This will return your layer's parent View.

Comment: Thanks for the ans, but I think I would rather maintain a separate property for the view.

Comment: yes sure.. you can maintain property or tag or class name.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if you have a commonly-used `CALayer`-subclass and you need to "call into the view" then it looks to me like that view will need to conform to a *protocol* in order for this to work correctly.

In that case you will need to store a reference to the view within the layer using KVC:

```
[layer setValue:view forKey:MyViewKey];
```

Where `MyViewKey` can be declared as part of the `CALayer`-subclass code:

```
extern NSString * const MyViewKey;
```

and will be defined something like:

```
NSString * const MyViewKey = @"Hello Mum";
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm missing something, but isn't this same as maintaing a property in the layer subclass?

Comment: @Adithya It's exactly the same, yes.